# Loaded array is not binding to angular directive in ng-options in a .net app

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs

I have an array which is referred to an api controller and it's response status is 200. While consoling the array , i have the expected data into it.

But when i try to bind that with aspx using ng-options directive, the dropdown is not populated.

Angular Code:

```
       ERMApp.controller("CascadeDeleteController",
function ($scope, $http, $sce, $rootScope, commondatafactory, academicsetupfactory) {

    $rootScope.loading = true;
    $scope.successMessage = "";
    $scope.successMessageHtml = "";
    $scope.errorMessage = "";
    $scope.errorMessageHtml = "";
    $scope.errorLabelStyle = { color: 'red' };
    $scope.PrimaryTables = [];
    $scope.PrimaryTableNames = [];

    $scope.newCascade = Object.create(null);
    $scope.showForm = true;

    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.newCascade = Object.create(null);
    };

    $scope.validation = function () {
        $scope.successMessage = "";
        $scope.successMessageHtml = "";
        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        $scope.errorMessageHtml = "";
        var messages = "";
        var validationResults = regula.validate();
        for (var i = 0; i < validationResults.length; i++) {
            var validationResult = validationResults[i];
            messages += validationResult.message + "<br />";
            $scope.errorMessage = messages;
        }
        if ($scope.errorMessage.length > 0) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            $scope.errorMessageHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(angular.copy($scope.errorMessage));
        }
    }


    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        regula.bind();

        jQuery("#parentTable").blur(function () {

            $scope.newCascade.ParentTable = jQuery("#parentTable").val();


            $scope.getParentField($scope.newCascade.ParentTable);

        });
    });

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $scope.showForm = false;
        $scope.successMessage = "";
        $scope.successMessageHtml = "";
        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        $scope.errorMessageHtml = "";
        $scope.loadData();
    }

    $scope.ParentTableNames = function () {

        $http.get('/api/CommonData/GetTableNameList')
            .success(function(data, status) {
                $rootScope.loading = false;
                $scope.PrimaryTableNames = [];
                $scope.PrimaryTableNames = data;
                //console.log($scope.PrimaryTableNames);
                $("#parentTable").kendoAutoComplete({
                    dataSource: data,
                    filter: "startswith",
                    minLength: 3
                });
                if ($scope.PrimaryTableNames && $scope.PrimaryTableNames.length)
                    $scope.showForm = false;
            });
    }
    $scope.ParentTableNames();

    $scope.getParentField = function (parentField) {


        $http.get("/api/CommonData/GetParentField?parentField=" + parentField)
        .success(function (data, status) {

            $rootScope.loading = false;
            $scope.PrimaryTables = [];
            $scope.PrimaryTables = data;
            console.log($scope.PrimaryTables);
            if ($scope.PrimaryTables && $scope.PrimaryTables.length)
                $scope.showForm = false;
        });
    }




    $scope.Add = function () {
        $scope.newSemesterConfiguration = Object.create(null);
        $scope.showForm = true;
        $scope.successMessage = "";
        $scope.successMessageHtml = "";
        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        $scope.errorMessageHtml = "";
    }

});

The Binding part in aspx:

       <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/App_MasterPages/BackOfficeMasterPage.master" CodeBehind="CascadeDelete.aspx.cs" Inherits="ERMAdmin_Inc.administration.CascadeDelete" %>
```

```
<h4>Cascade Delete Configuration Setup</h4>
```

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx?val=Administration">Administration</a></li>
    <li>Cascade Delete Configuration Setup</li>
</ul>
```

```
<script src="../Scripts/ScriptAdmin/angularControllers/Administration/CascadeDeleteSetupController.js"></script>
```

```
<div data-ng-controller="CascadeDeleteController" id="angularpage"></div>

<div ng-show="successMessage.length" id="successmessageDiv" class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>
    <p>{{successMessage}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-show="errorMessage.length" id="errormessageDiv" class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>
    <p ng-bind-html="errorMessageHtml"></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"> Add / Edit Cascade Delete</h4>
                </div>
            <div class="panel-body nopadding">
                <div class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-2 control-label">Parent Table</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-8">

                            <input  id="parentTable" type="text" class="form-control" 
                                    data-constraints='@Required(message = "Parent Table is required.")'
                                    data-ng-model="newCascade.ParentTable">
                                <span class="mandatoryFieldMarker">*</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-2 control-label">Parent Field Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">

                            <select 
                                data-ng-model="newCascade.ParentTableField"
                                data-ng-options="o.COLUMN_NAME for o in PrimaryTables" 

                                class="form-control mandatoryfield" 
                                data-constraints='@Required(message = "ParentTableField is required.")' 
                                >
                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                    <%--<option value="">All Departments</option>--%>
                                </select>
                                <span class="mandatoryFieldMarker">*</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-list" style="text-align: right; margin-right: 1.5%">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="save()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Save</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="cancel()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Cancel</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="cancel()"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i>Back to List</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="saveAndAdd()"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i>Save and Add more</a>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



<div data-ng-show="PrimaryTables.length && !showForm">

    <div style="text-align: right">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="Add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New </a>

        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrimaryTables` is bound to the `$scope` of the `CascadeDeleteController`.
However, the ngController is placed on a div, which is immediately closed.

`<div data-ng-controller="CascadeDeleteController" id="angularpage"></div>`

What you need is

```
`<div data-ng-controller="CascadeDeleteController" id="angularpage">
    {{PrimaryTables}}
    <-- select with ngOptions here
</div>`
```